# Hyprland 0.37.1 error

Tags: window-manager

I'm using the pre-compiled binaries for Hyprland 0.37.1 on Ubuntu 23.10 and get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libhyprlang.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I was advised on other forums to make a symlink (named above) to libhyprlang.so.0.5.0 which I have done. Still getting the same error.

Hyprland was working fine with 0.35 for me. 0.36 caused me to lose the ability to drag floating windows. And now this, and I can't use it at all.

Just making this post here to see if others have encountered the same thing. It's already been reported on the git forums, etc.

Thanks.